# How to reuse the same widgets in different wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have to the following page which has a widget called press as you can see in the screenshot
[image]

I had created another page (manually and by cloning pulgin) and I can't reuse the same widget in the new page.
Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: It sounds like you are creating a new theme page, can you publishing the source code for this page and its name. I believe within the theme, the widgets need to be registered to specific post/page types. In your case, the first page has this, your new second page doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

you can add sidebar in particular page template

Ex. sidebar slug name : "left-sidebar"

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ) ) : ?>
       <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or

you can use below plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-widgets/

Page template section screenshot

For Ex. About Us Template

[image]

Comment: if I want to load the widget each time I have load the page what should I add to my page template

Comment: create child theme and copy your page and past in child theme  then add above code in particular " section or div" in your page.

Comment: why not using the same template for both pages?

Comment: I have tried to use the same templates for both pages and it didn't work for me

Comment: yes you can use the same template for both page. just select page template when you are creating page.

Comment: please check screenshot in answer

Comment: I did the same but my page has posts widget inside it this is what called widget press in my question screenshout I want to get this widget in my new page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146840/discussion-between-shital-marakana-and-mohammed).